# POST Data not being retrieved in Play! framework

Tags: json, post, playframework

I have a view that is posting a set of valid json such as

```
[{"profile_sfid":"00eA0000000l3v7IAA", "object":[{"name":"null", "viewable":[],"editable":[]},{"name":"account", "viewable":["Object Type","Salesforce ID"],"editable":["Test Multi","Test Checkbox"]},{"name":"contact", "viewable":["Object Type","Salesforce ID"],"editable":["Test Multi","Test Checkbox"]}]}]
```

to a route at /saveAssignments. The post operation is returning a 200 success message but the controller method is returning null for the json on the logger statement

```
public static void saveAssignments(JsonElement json)
{
    Logger.debug("Hey guys, here is my json! " + json);
}
```

Using the following GSONBinder for JsonElement

```
@Global
public class GsonBinder implements TypeBinder<JsonElement> {   

@Override   
public Object bind(String name, Annotation[] annotations, String value,  Class actualClass, Type genericType) throws Exception 
{       
    return new JsonParser().parse(value); 
}
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, as I am unsure why it isn't accepting this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar, using a pojo class which has the same structure as the json object to receive (in the example, the "Player" class):

```
public class Player {
    public String name;
    ...
}

public static void addPlayerJSON(JsonObject body) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Player newPlayer = gson.fromJson(body, Player.class);
    Logger.debug("Player name: " + newPlayer.name);
    ...
}
```

The "newPlayer" object has the data parsed from json.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a param "json={your json}" you will receive it on server side. or rename the "json" parameter to "body" so it can consume the json posted in the request body.